# Ignoring NAs while calculaging average wage of each group using ddply

Tags: r, dplyr, na

I am trying to calculate average wage for each group (men/women) using `ddply`. There are a few NAs in my data so my code doesn't work. How do I ignore NA's in this case?

My code:

```
Mu <- ddply(data, "sex", summarise, grp.mean=mean(wage_total))
```

I am new with Rstudio so help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `na.rm=TRUE`

```
Mu <- ddply(data, "sex", summarise, grp.mean = mean(wage_total, na.rm=TRUE))
```